# SQL Xml for Xpath query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

Trying to return the value of an XML field via Xpath query.

Here is what the XML looks like in a snap shot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
<ArrayOfCustomProperty xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
<CustomProperty>      
    <DeveloperId>Test123</DeveloperId>      
    <Key>AgreedToTerms</Key>      
    <Value>True</Value>    
</CustomProperty>    
<CustomProperty>      
    <DeveloperId>Test456</DeveloperId>      
    <Key>ValidForLoyaltyPoints</Key>      
    <Value>False</Value>    
</CustomProperty>  
</ArrayOfCustomProperty>
```

(sorry for the poorly-formatted XML...StackOverflows RCE is having issues with rendering it out.  The ArrayOfCustomProperty is closed at the end, just not displayed for some reason)

This query works for me....

```
  SET @return = CAST(CAST(@xmlData AS xml).query('ArrayOfCustomProperty/CustomProperty/Key[text()=sql:variable("@key")]/../Value/text()') AS nvarchar(255))
```

It allows me to have a function where the parameters are @xmlData and @key for what needs to be searched.  I need to have another function (or might modify this one) where I can also search the [DeveloperId] node as well, so a third parameter will be passed in as @devId.  I've tried quite a few different things but nothing has worked for me yet.  I'd like a query where I can get the [Value] when [DeveloperId] and [Key] are present using the same structure (if possible) to how the current Xpath query works.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `xml` data to a table and then process the table. Something like this.

```
declare @xml xml=N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
<ArrayOfCustomProperty xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
<CustomProperty>      
    <DeveloperId>Test123</DeveloperId>      
    <Key>AgreedToTerms</Key>      
    <Value>True</Value>    
</CustomProperty>    
<CustomProperty>      
    <DeveloperId>Test456</DeveloperId>      
    <Key>ValidForLoyaltyPoints</Key>      
    <Value>False</Value>    
</CustomProperty>  
</ArrayOfCustomProperty>',
@key varchar(50)

;with cte as (
select t.v.value('DeveloperId[1]','varchar(50)') DeveloperId,
    t.v.value('Key[1]','varchar(50)') [Key],
    t.v.value('Value[1]','varchar(50)') [Value]
from @xml.nodes('ArrayOfCustomProperty/CustomProperty') t(v)
)
select * from cte
where [Key] = @key
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This does work, though I was hoping to use the inline 'query' functionality if possible.  I will adapt my solution to use a table unless I see another answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: This works correctly, but can be done better. Just imagine big XMLs with a lot of `<CustomProperty>` elements. Your approach has to return all of them, just to through most of the result away again. You might check my answer how you can use a *predicate* to return only the needed element.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather try to return as little as possible from the XML.
The best was to reduce the amount the engine has to parse to the needed minimum.
And you should avoid backward-navigation using `../`. This is a well known performance killer.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
<ArrayOfCustomProperty xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
<CustomProperty>      
    <DeveloperId>Test123</DeveloperId>      
    <Key>AgreedToTerms</Key>      
    <Value>True</Value>    
</CustomProperty>    
<CustomProperty>      
    <DeveloperId>Test456</DeveloperId>      
    <Key>ValidForLoyaltyPoints</Key>      
    <Value>False</Value>    
</CustomProperty>  
</ArrayOfCustomProperty>');
```

--Your Key-variable

```
DECLARE @key VARCHAR(100)='ValidForLoyaltyPoints' ;
```

--the Query

```
SELECT cp.value('(DeveloperId/text())[1]','nvarchar(250)') AS DeveloperId
      ,cp.value('(Value/text())[1]','nvarchar(250)') AS Value
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes('/ArrayOfCustomProperty/CustomProperty[(Key/text())[1]=sql:variable("@key")]') A(cp);
```

The `XPath/XQuery` within `.nodes()` will dive down to `<CustomProperty>` and will return the one with a `<Key>`, where the key's text is like the given filter. The found `<CustomProperty>` is returned. Using `.value()` we can read the elements below this given property.

### UPDATE

It looks, as if you'd try to fetch the `<Value>` as a scalar value depending in `<DeveloperId>` and `<Key>`. You can use a simple predicate to query both at once:

```
DECLARE @key VARCHAR(100)='ValidForLoyaltyPoints' ;
DECLARE @devId VARCHAR(100)='Test456';
--the Query

SELECT t.YourXml.value(N'(/ArrayOfCustomProperty
                          /CustomProperty[(DeveloperId/text())[1]=sql:variable("@devId") 
                                      and (Key/text())[1]=sql:variable("@key")]
                          /Value/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @tbl t;
```

You read this as

- Dive into the array
- Dive deeper into CustomProperty
- Find an element, where the filter matches ...
- ... and return its value

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am going to run some tests between your answer and the previous one to see the performance results.  Also, thanks for the extra information.

Comment: @JohnPete22 Great! Please be so kind and let us know the differences... In general I'd say: The more CPs you have within one `<Array>`, the bigger the difference will grow...

Comment: I'm having some issues with the function (not extremely proficient with these XML queries especially in a function).  The function will take  two different parameters -- @key and developerId.  I need to return the [Value] where key = [Key] and developerId = [DeveloperId].  Right now this returns the DeveloperId and Value.  Is there anyway to add another Cross Apply (I can't seem to figure it out) for the DeveloperID?

Comment: @JohnPete22, That means, you pass in two parameters and want to return just the scalar value? This needs no `apply` at all. Just both parameters with `and` in the XQuery predicate within `.value()`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I posted what I "thought" you meant with your latest comment as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Shnugo

Is this what you meant with your last comment?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (@xmlData)

SELECT t.YourXml.value('(/ArrayOfCustomProperty/CustomProperty/Value/text())[1]','nvarchar(250)') AS Value 
FROM @tbl t
WHERE t.YourXml.value('(/ArrayOfCustomProperty/CustomProperty/Key/text())[1]','nvarchar(250)') = @key 
AND
t.YourXml.value('(/ArrayOfCustomProperty/CustomProperty/DeveloperId/text())[1]','nvarchar(250)') = @devId
```

Comment: @Shnugo not sure if the tag in the answer worked, so going to add it here. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi John, I've added something to my answer. Neither the tag within the answer, nor the tag in the comment in this answer will trigger an alert. Because I haven't participated here.

Comment: One more hint: If this is not meant as an answer, you should rather use the edit option of your question to add to this.